# Which file defines the LESSOPEN environment variable?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, less

On my Linux machine - I do the following:

```
$ env | grep -i LESSOPEN
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
```

So from `env` command I see that:

```
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
```

I want to change the variable `LESSOPEN`, so I do the following search in order to find where it's located, so I can make this change.

```
$ grep -Ril "LESSOPEN" /
```

But the `grep` search did not find any such file with `LESSOPEN`.

Comment: Which distribution are you running? Which version? The files that define these things vary greatly between different distributions.

Comment: DAVID MA SLOMAHA , first - my linux version is 5.3 , I run the find command from the "/" , and I really not understand why find + grep not found this param

Comment: Are you sure this didn't find a hit? `grep -R … /` would spew out a lot of errors and run for a very long time because it traverses all filesystems and tries to enter directories and read files that you have no permission to read.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Red Hat and CentOS systems, it is defined in `/etc/profile.d/less.sh`. On version 5, this contains

```
# less initialization script (sh)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe.sh ] && export LESSOPEN="${LESSOPEN-|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s}"
```

On other systems, such as version 7, the value may be `||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s`; there is a slightly different interpretation between values that begin with `|` and `||`, detailed in the [man page for less](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less).

You can either edit that file if you want all users of bash-like shells on your system to see a different value, or override it for yourself by editing `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to have an `export LESSOPEN=whatever` line.

On Linux systems, `grep -r string /` or `grep -R string /` may run into problems when reading certain special files. `grep` will hang when reading `/dev/rfkill`, and, due to what I believe is a buffer allocation bug, will run out of memory reading certain large files in `/proc`. An alternative is to exclude `/dev` and `/proc`:

```
find / '(' -path /proc -o -path /dev ')' -prune -o -type f -exec grep -il lessopen {} +
```

Comment: I ran across the `||` version in RHEL 7, but I can't find `||` in the linked man page, or an historical version of it. The best explanation is in [a RHEL bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1254837#c15), which says that it makes less handle non-zero exit statuses from the script.